# importNode and Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have a dynamic page where, with a bar button, I can change the main `div` content.
Most of the pages are static except one, which contains JavaScript (RGraph charts).
That's why in order to make it working I use the following code:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append( 'action', 'charts' );
// clean the content
var myNode = document.getElementById("contentView");
while (myNode.firstChild)
{
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
}
// set the new content
var div = document.createElement("div");
var t = document.createElement('template');
t.innerHTML =  _connectToServer( data );
for (var i=0; i < t.content.childNodes.length; i++)
{
    var node = document.importNode(t.content.childNodes[i], true);
    div.appendChild(node);
}
document.getElementById("contentView").appendChild(div);
```

The problem is that as far as I see (and I read) such a code is not compatible with Microsoft Edge, and I would like to make it going with Edge as well.

What's the best way to succeed?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting the notion that Edge doesn't support importNode, I created this version of your code: http://jsbin.com/voyibetevu/edit?html,js,output (changed it to use "hello" rather than fetch data) and it repros the same in Chrome as EdgeHTML 16. Let me know if I'm missing something and I'm more than happy to take a look.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works with plain text but as I said I am using such a function because within the data fetched I have executable code (javascript). In fact, turning your example in javascript doesn't work: http://jsbin.com/zenarituse/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I took this over to our DOM team to better understand this interop issue.

This is actually a Chrome bug per spec. What happens is when you create a template element and place innerHTML inside of it, it is treated as a DocumentFragment. And a template element's contents can't have executable script.

Here are the relavent spec links that cover this:

- [InnerHTML](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-element-innerhtml)
- [Template Element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-template-element)

To work around this, as I pointed to earlier you'll need to create a `<script>` tag not within a `<template>` element and utilize textContent. Here's an example of this: http://jsbin.com/gizayuyape/edit?html,js,output

Or here is the code:

```
// Using textContent
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.textContent = 'document.write("Script textContent");';
body.appendChild(s);
```

Good news, at least on the interop front, is that Chrome has fixed this issue starting in version 67:

[image]